# Make a row in a table unique

Tags: database

Is it possible to make a row in a database table unique? If so how? I know you can make a field unique so for example 'John' could not appear twice in a name field. But what if I have something like:

```
name: John
id: 1
foreign_key: 1

name: John
id: 2
foreign_key: 1
```

In this instance it would be fine as they are the same but different.

Where as this would be prevented:

```
name: John
id: 1
foreign_key: 1

name: John
id: 1
foreign_key: 1
```

It's difficult to demonstrate as the obvious answer would be to make the foreign_key unique but in my case it's a many to many relationship so the ID or foreign key could appear many many times but shouldn't ever have the same data in all the columns.

I.e this should work:

```
id: 1
fKey: 2
afKey: 3

id: 1
fKey: 3
afKey: 3
```

BUT not when fKey and afKey match in two rows like:

```
id: 1
fKey: 2
afKey: 3

id: 1
fKey: 2
afKey: 3
```

Comment: As bad a design as I think it is, you can do this with a unique constraint across all the columns of the table. The question is, why do you need to do this?

Comment: Then create a unique index on all columns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make the row unique you could make all 3 columns a composite primary key.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/multiple-column-indexes.html

Comment: There are 3 columns. One primary and two foreign keys. And only the primary is actually unique. The other two can REPEAT the data but not in both at the same time.

Comment: Yes but since the entire row has to be unique, the 3 columns are effectively a composite primary key.  Otherwise they wouldn't have to be unique!

Comment: But a primary is unique! Only the first can have this. The other two repeat data and are not unique only combined are the unique!

Comment: Yes, just try it, it will work.  What has to be unique is all of the columns in the composite index together.  You don't have to make them a primary key if you don't want to, you can just make a unique index.  But it is natural for that to be a pk, unless you have an identity column off to the side that you want to have as the pk to more easily use as an fk elsewhere

Comment: How? I can't have more than one primary key in my table! It errors and says only one field can be the primary key. And if I make the other just indexes then the data still repeats and if I make them unique then it prevents me from repeating data in one of the columns which isn't what I want.

Comment: Hang on is this what you mean?  `UNIQUE KEY `topic_id` (`topic_id`,`post_id`)`

Comment: OK, you can only have one primary key but that primary key can be more than one column - I think you're trying to add an extra primary key.

Comment: Something like: PRIMARY KEY (topic_id, post_id, your_other_id)

Comment: I can't do that as the Primary is the auto_increment and can only have one column according to my error!

Comment: OK so you'll never have any duplicates across all 3 columns because your auto increment value will always stop it from happening :-)

Comment: If you have an auto increment value in your table, chances are that should be used as the primary key.  It sounds like you don't even need it.  Why not just get rid of your auto increment column and make a composite primary key across your other two foreign key columns?

Comment: I have no idea what you mean about the composite primary key Chris, but that code I posted fixes the unique issue so I take you can make it so that two columns must be unique for a row in a table? In any case I'll accept your answer for the help. But need to fix the bigger issue now: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10219020/updating-and-removing-unique-join-relationships-in-cakephp

Comment: This might help explain a composite primary key for you: http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jeffs/archive/2007/08/23/composite_primary_keys.aspx.  And yes, by applying a unique key to two columns in a table you can force that the combination of both columns always be unique throughout all rows in the table.