# Updating and removing unique join relationships in CakePHP

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

**Edit: What I need help with is deleting all the relationships between a topic and post in the topics_posts table so that it cleans up the relationships and removes old ones. Then the rest of the code SHOULD work fine as all the issues will be resolved because we deleted the relationships before adding them.**

In my CakePHP application I have Posts and Topics (topics are unique and have an id) and they are linked to each other via Topic_Posts which handles the relationships between a post and a topic.

However if a user edits a post that has relationships and they save it, instead of just amending the relationships it will duplicate them in the Topic_posts table and also does not remove them if the user removes a topic from a post!

What is the best way of dealing with this? I have heard talk about removing ALL the relationships for that post and then re-adding them is the cleanest and best way to to deal with said scenario but again how do I do this?

This is the code that handles the saving of the topics (which does check that topics are NOT duplicated) but doesn't check that they are duplicated relationships NOR does it remove relationships.

```
public function savePostTopics($postId, $topics)
    {
        // Explode the topics by comma, so we have an array to run through
        $topics = explode(',', $topics);
        // Array for collecting all the data
        $collection = array();

        foreach($topics as $topic)
        {
            // Trim it so remove unwanted white spaces in the beginning and the end.
            $topic = trim($topic);

            // Make it all lowercase for consistency of tag names
            $topic = strtolower($topic);

            // Check if we already have a topic like this
            $controlFind = $this->find(
                'first',
                array(
                    'conditions' => array(
                        'title' => $topic
                    ),
                    'recursive' => -1
                )
            );

            // No record found
            if(!$controlFind)
            {
                $this->create();
                if(
                    !$this->save(
                        array(
                            'title' => $topic
                        )
                    )
                )
                {
                    // If only one saving fails we stop the whole loop and method.
                    return false;
                }
                else
                {
                    $temp = array(
                        'TopicPost' => array(
                            'topic_id' => $this->id,
                            'post_id' => $postId
                        )
                    );
                }
            }
            else
            {
                $temp = array(
                    'TopicPost' => array(
                        'topic_id' => $controlFind['Topic']['id'],
                        'post_id' => $postId
                    )
                );
            }

            $collection[] = $temp;
        }

        return $this->TopicPost->saveMany($collection, array('validate' => false));
    }
```

Here are the associations:

```
Post.php
class Post extends AppModel
{
    public $name = 'Post';

    public $belongsTo = 'User';

    public $hasMany = array('Answer');

    // Has many topics that belong to topic post join table... jazz
    public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
        'Topic' => array('with' => 'TopicPost')
    );
}

Topic.php
class Topic extends AppModel
{
    public $hasMany = array(
        'TopicPost'
    );
}

TopicPost.php
class TopicPost extends AppModel {
    public $belongsTo = array(
        'Topic', 'Post'
    );
}
```

EDIT: I have done the following to make the two columns unique against each other:

```
`id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `topic_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `post_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `unique_row` (`topic_id`,`post_id`)
```

but when I do an update I get a SQL error so basically Cake isn't handling this properly... How do I fix this issue as it only partly solves the problem by preventing the data being repeated! Also how do I deal with when removing topics as I want the relationship removing from topic_posts but no idea how to do it?

```
Database Error
Error: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '2-107' for key 2

SQL Query: INSERT INTO `db52704_favorr`.`topic_posts` (`topic_id`, `post_id`) VALUES (2, 107)
```

Comment: Any updates? As very confused on this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you don't need the column `id` in Topic_Posts.  You should remove it and instead use this:

```
  `topic_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `post_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`topic_id`, `post_id`)
```

This will mean that every topic that is added to a post can only be added once (it's effectively what you've got now, only a lot tidier).

The reason you're getting an SQL error when you update a post is because you're adding every topic to the post in Topic_Posts regardless of whether or not they existed before.

Your snippet of code is saying:

- For each topic the user has added to the post, do this:

  - If the topic doesn't exist, add it to the Topic table (it looks like you've forgotten to add it to the Topic_Posts table here)
  - If the topic does exist, add it to the Topic_Posts table (without checking if it already exists there)

Instead you want it to say something like this:

- For each topic the user has added to the post, do this:

  - If the topic doesn't exist, add it to the Topic table and then add it to the Topic_Posts table (since it's a foreign key in Topic_Posts, you must create it in the Topic table first)
  - If the topic does exist...
  - If it doesn't exist for this post in the Topic_Posts table, add it, otherwise ignore it

**An alternative way of doing it to handle the removal of topics could be:**

- Remove all rows from Topic_Posts for the current post
- For each topic the user has added to the post, do this:

  - If the topic doesn't exist, add it to the Topic table and then add it to the Topic_Posts table (since it's a foreign key in Topic_Posts, you must create it in the Topic table first)
  - If the topic does exist, add it to Topic_Posts table

You don't need to worry about checking if a topic exists for that post in Topic_Posts this way as the first step is to remove all topics for that post.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Okay that helps :) but any chance you help modify the snippet of code to work more what you described as I not sure how to do it. Also what about handling removing of topics from a post and deleting the reference in the topic_post table, as you don't mention that. Thanks

Comment: Sorry I've never used CakePHP so your guess at how the code should look is as good as mine!

Comment: I've added an alternative way that would handle removing topics from an updated post.